# Необходимо вывести все числа от 1 до n, не кратные 3 на Python с циклом while

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пользователь вводит число n — число коробок. Программа должна вывести все числа от 1 до n, не кратные 3.

Как дальше быть?

```
a = int(input('Введите число'))
i = 1
while i <= a:
```

Comment: Ясно. Выполняйте.

Answer (score 2):

```py
n = int(input())

i = 1
while i < n:
    if i % 3 != 0:
        print(i)
    i += 1
```

---

***stdin:***

```
10
```

***stdout:***

```py
1
2
4
5
7
8
```

Comment: @Водзя Нет, это не так. Вы уверены, что запускаете мой код? И при чём тут _"счёт не кратных чисел"_, в вопросе речь идёт о том, чтобы _"вывести все числа от 1 до n, не кратные 3"_. Привёл пример входных-выходных данных.

Comment: Спасибо большое!Вы правы.А как сделать числа, кратные 3?

Comment: @Водзя Замените условие на `if i % 3 == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(1, int(input()) + 1, 3):
    print(i, i + 1, end=" ")
print()
```